# Background image not visible when app runs on device Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

`android:background="@drawable/bkg1"`

Android studio show the image,but when app run on phone, doesn't show.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/bkg1"  >
```

Comment: post your code and xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem could be in the picture so try to use this code (if it shows the red background then consider using another picture)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#c04444">
```

Comment: why use `android:orientation="vertical"` for a `RelativeLayout` ?

Comment: should picture has special resolation??
my picture is 1920*1080

Comment: you can remove the orientation as zahidul pointed out. It was a linear layout and I just changed it to relative and the orientation stayed. Play around with pictures and see which ones are being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to create any other thing on this layout like create button. if button is not visible than your layout is not set. and if it visible than try to change image or uninstall the apk from device and build project than run.